# How can I write tests in Typescript Playwright, using the Page Object Model and inheriting from a base page class, so that they will run in UI mode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, playwright, playwright-test

I'm new to both playwright and typescript, so this is probably a very silly question.

If I have a test that looks like this:

```
import { test, expect, Locator, Page } from '@playwright/test';

test('whatever', async ({page}) => {
  page.goto('https://google.ca'/);
})
```

and I run "npx playwright test --ui", it comes up no problem.

I've created two page objects, one of which is a base class that the page I care about extends. If I modify my test script to look like this:

```
import { test, expect, Locator, Page } from '@playwright/test';
import { YoutubeMyoutubeMastheadPage } from '../pages/youtubeMastheadPage';

test('Log in to youtube', async ({ page }) => {
    const masthead = new YoutubeMyoutubeMastheadPage(page);

    await masthead.signInToYoutube();
    await expect(page.locator('xpath=//img[@alt="Avatar image"]'));
  });

test('whatever', async ({page}) => {
  page.goto('https://google.ca'/);
})
```

and I run "npx playwright test --ui", it says no tests are found and simply shows the youtubeMastheadPage.

youtubeMastheadPage looks like this:

```
export class YoutubeMyoutubeMastheadPage extends basePage{

    readonly page: Page;

    constructor(page: Page){
        super(page)
        this.page = page;

    }
[other methods]
}
```

I tried to implement this based on the POM from the playwright docs, but can't seem to get it to recognize my test when there is a page object imported.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written should work.

However, I noticed that `page.goto('https://google.ca'/);` is invalid (notice the syntax error).

My suspicion is that you are getting a syntax error and that is why it says no tests found.

Also, the expect function that you have used is not complete, it should be in the form `expect(page.locator('...')).toBe(...)`. You need to check some property or value using expect function, as in the example below:

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Page object creation from the `youtubeMastheadPage` page.

```
readonly page: Page;
```

That should solve your issue.